# How to properly function annotate function-argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, type-hinting

I want my function to be annotated that it takes another function as an argument. At first I thought that this is going to work just fine:

```
def my_function(func_argument: function):
    pass
```

however function is unresolved reference. I looked through builtins and it is indeed not there, unlike str, int and others I typically use. However, it has to be somewhere, because:

```
>>> def my_function():
...     pass
... 
>>> x = my_function
>>> type(x)
<class 'function'>
>>> type(x).__name__
'function'
```

Where is the function class defined, why isn't it in builtins? Is my original try supposed to be the correct solution? For now I went with annotating it with `types.FunctionType`, but it doesn't feel right because everywhere else we hint `str` not `types.StringType`. And importing types just for one annotation is also weird. `typing` library also doesn't have anything it that would help me replace this.

Also, how would FunctionType work with a type annotation enforcing library (I saw few of those flying around)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [`Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#callable):

> Frameworks expecting *callback functions* of specific signatures might
>   be type hinted using `Callable[[Arg1Type, Arg2Type], ReturnType]`

---

```
from typing import Callable

def my_function(func_argument: Callable[..., ReturnType]): # replace ReturnType with return type of func_argument
    pass
```

Comment: I overlooked Callable in typing, but it actually makes a lot of sense to use as it works for both lambda and function.  I kinda dislike that it has to have a return type, as not all functions return something - should they then have None as a second argument? Also it's not too clear to someone inexperienced with typing library, but I guess it's more of a typing issue than SO question, thanks :)

Comment: @iScrE4m `None` can be used for functions that *do not return anything*, they actually return `None`.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks a lot!